# How to filter rows of dataframe if the values from 2 columns lie in between start and end region?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr, filter

I have a dataframe: regionarea

```
dput(region_area)
structure(list(region1 = c(144969, 134134, 178890), region2 = c(165009,
143145, 179812), region3 = c(14575436, 24346457, 34142562), region4 = c(15346473,
34545741, 35647244)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))
```

I have a start and end region: checkvalues:

```
dput(check_values)
structure(list(start_Region = 144812, end_region = 178910), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-1L))
```

I want to filter out the dataframe if the two columns region1 and region 2 has any values between start and end region:

```
For example:
regionarea:
region1 region2 region3 region4 
144969   165009  14575436  15346473
134134   143145  24346457  34545741
178890   179812  34142562  35647244

start_Region <- 144812 
end_region <- 178910

return rows:
region1 region2 region3 region4 
    144969   165009  14575436  15346473
    178890   179812  34142562  35647244
```

Based on my condition: if any value from sequence between region1 and region2 lies between start and end region: select that row from the dataframe and return it:
Based on this: it will select 1st and 3rs row: since `seq(144969,165009)` lies in between `seq(start,end region)`
and `seq(178890,179812)` lies between `seq(start,end region)`

Is there any way to do this faster?
I tried it in using for loop and seq command but its taking a lot of time:
My code for reference:

```
if(any((seq(checkvalues$start_region[i],checkvalues$end_Region[i]) %in% seq(region_area$region1[j],region_area$region2[j],1))==TRUE)){ 
      y <- region_area[j,] ##get the selected region
value <- y
      }
```

I tried to use for loop but since my dataframe is huge

```
dim(regionarea)
31618129        5
```

its taking more than 7 days to run the code.
I would really appreciate some guidance on how to solve this problem
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in `tidyverse`, which is often faster than loops and is memory efficient. However, I believe you are dealing with genomics data. If that is the case, you should consider parsing the data using bash commands such as `sed` and `awk`.

```
library(tidyverse)
region_area %>% 
  filter((region1 > check_values$start_Region & region1 < check_values$end_region) | (region2 > check_values$start_Region & region2 < check_values$end_region))
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that what you are looking for is *overlaps*, since some of your example values for `region1` and `region2` do not lie in the interval `start_Region` - `end_Region`, but the range `region1` - `region2` does have overlap.

You could try the [ivs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ivs/vignettes/ivs.html) package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ivs)

regionarea %>% 
  filter(iv_overlaps(iv(region1, region2), iv(144812, 178910)))
```

Result:

```
  region1 region2  region3  region4
1  144969  165009 14575436 15346473
2  178890  179812 34142562 35647244
```

If you are working with genomic ranges and intervals, you may want to look at [IRanges](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/IRanges.html).

Comment: thank you for the solution, i will look into IRanges package.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple columns to check, you can use `if_any` in `filter`, and make use of the `between` function to check on ranges.

```r
library(dplyr)

region_area |> filter(if_any(region1:region2, ~ between(.x, check_values$start_Region, check_values$end_region)))

  region1 region2  region3  region4
1  144969  165009 14575436 15346473
2  178890  179812 34142562 35647244
```