# how to filter dataset faster instead of individually doing using for loop for large dataset

Tags: r, for-loop, select, dplyr, filter

I have two dataset:

one is a position vector called "positionchr" and other is a dataframe called "interaction region"

```
dput(positionchr[1:])
c(71526L,124659L, 144370L, 125121L)

dput(interactionregion[1:5,3:4])
structure(list(rf1 = c(40000L, 80000L, 120000L, 499336L, 459336L
), rt1 = c(80000L, 120000L, 160000L, 501617L, 499336L)), row.names = c(NA,
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to check whether each value in positionchr vector lies between the two-column value of the interation region dataframe.
I have attached both the dataset for reference.
I have written a code using for loop to check: but since my positionchr length is its taking a lot of time to run the analysis:

```
pos <- positionchr$pos
##now search whether this pos is present in between rf1 and rt1 in the dataframe or not:
selected_region <- data.frame() ##create a null dataframe to add values for the selected position  if present in between rf1 and rt1 of the interaction region dataframe
for(j in 1:length(pos)){ ##j represent each position
positionval <- pos[j]
value <- interactionregion  %>% filter(positionval >= rf1 & positionval <= rt1) %>% mutate(positionused=j)
selected_region <- rbind(selected_pregion,value) 
}
```

My final output should look like:

```
initial data:
positionval <- 124659
rf1 rt1 
 rf2    rt2
40000  80000
80000  120000
120000 160000
499336 501617
459336 499336

##selected final region: the position lies between between 3rd row so select them


 final data:
    rf1    rt1  snpused
    
    120000 160000 124659
```

so basically, select the columns of the interaction region dataframe where the position chr lies in between and also add a new column stating that this particular position was used and indicating that it lies between the two-column value rf1 rt1 position used.

Is there any way to deal with this in order to speed the process.
Thank you.

Comment: > pos <- positionchr$pos
Error in positionchr$pos : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems very similar to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76880220/how-to-filter-rows-of-dataframe-if-the-values-from-2-columns-lie-in-between-star) and again I would recommend the [GenomicRanges](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/GenomicRanges/inst/doc/GenomicRangesIntroduction.html) package for solving these kinds of problems.

You could also use `fuzzyjoin` if you convert `positionchr` to a data frame.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

positionchr <- data.frame(snp = c(71526,124659, 144370, 125121))

interactionregion <- data.frame(rf1 = c(40000, 80000, 120000, 499336, 459336),
                                rt1 = c(80000, 120000, 160000, 501617, 499336))

fuzzy_join(positionchr, 
           interactionregion, 
           by = c("snp" = "rf1", "snp" = "rt1"), 
           match_fun = c(`>=`, `<=`))
```

Result:

```
     snp    rf1    rt1
1  71526  40000  80000
2 124659 120000 160000
3 144370 120000 160000
4 125121 120000 160000
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way, using `dplyr`'s `join_by()` function:

```
inner_join(positionchr, interactionregion, join_by(between(snp, rf1, rt1)))
```

Output:

```
     snp    rf1    rt1
1  71526  40000  80000
2 124659 120000 160000
3 144370 120000 160000
4 125121 120000 160000
```

For more information on `join_by()`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611717/can-dplyr-join-on-multiple-columns-or-composite-key/76937962#76937962).

Credit to Neil for the `positionchr` dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Your data is sorted with ranges. You are looking for `findInterval` and/or `cut`.

eg: `cut` gives you something like below

```
 vec <- sort(unique(unlist(interactionregion)))
 data.frame(between=cut(positionchr, vec, dig.lab = 7), positionchr)

          between positionchr
1   (40000,80000]       71526
2 (120000,160000]      124659
3 (120000,160000]      144370
4 (120000,160000]      125121
```

while `findInterval` can be used like shown below:

```
vec <- sort(unique(unlist(interactionregion)))
pos <- findInterval(positionchr,vec)
cbind(interactionregion[order(interactionregion$rf1)[pos],], positionchr)

       rf1    rt1 positionchr
1    40000  80000       71526
3   120000 160000      124659
3.1 120000 160000      144370
3.2 120000 160000      125121
```